# Stolen ETH on Myetherwallet.com

Tags: cpp-ethereum, myetherwallet

I have problem with stolen 205 ETH from myetherwallet.com
Story , in short:

My first login and creating account/wallet,  was on Jan 7 2017, when i deposited 205 eth.
ETHs was transferred from my account on Jan 27. 2017. 20 days AFTER.
  I cant imagine that someone hacked me on FIRST and ONLY time i logged in on 7.JAN and waited TWENTY days to take my ETHs.....
I saw missing ETH on FEB 28. 2017.
I use offline virtual machine for everything , VM is turned off at all times, i tuned it on on 28.FEB, when i wanted to transfer ETH on CEX.IO

Phishing is out of question, some hacking I just  can't imagine since i use  VM and everyday machine is under Kaspersky .... and didn't log there anymore ( also, I am 40 y/o and 20+ with PC every day)

Someone have any advice on this?

this are transactions:
my address is:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc7b2d9ecc4d433d79b917c30ceaffc66fa54baf3       from there 205 eth goes to

https://etherscan.io/address/0xc79ed05a7b3c3ab8b58e28be47f31bfca53a90d3       and then , 230 this time goes to:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x96fc4553a00c117c5b0bed950dd625d1c16dc894   account with 25 000+ transactions  ( later i found out it is a changelly.com ETH address)

this is transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f18583977b23b6e54e5a334614f6ff44b357c8e86797673815c22f7f6c7c9df

Sorry for any typo and my bad English , I am furious :(

I'm 100% sure i forgot something to write  :)

Thanks

PS. I didn't receive ANY mail, ANY notification ANYTHING , regarding transferring funds from my account....

Comment: If you do not have control over your ether anymore, I'm unsure how the community can help you with this. From what I've seen before, I'd say you did not use the original myetherwallet.com but a phishing site.

Comment: Longer discussion with speculation & clarification & my personal response on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5y4wg7/do_not_use_myetherwalletcom/

Answer (score 2):

> PS. I didn't receive ANY mail, ANY notification ANYTHING , regarding transferring funds from my account....

**myetherwallet.com doesn't store your funds, as your private key is always kept locally, so you can't have funds stolen from myetherwallet.**

myetherwallet.com is not a website, so much as it is a client side javascript wallet management application. So you wouldn't receive any emails, because they don't know your email, as myetherwallet.com is client side with the exception of broadcasting transactions to the network.

> Someone have any advice on this?

Are you sure it was the legitimate myetherwallet.com side you used? It sounds like you may have clicked on a scam link that you inadvertently sent your private key to?

---

I feel for you. I have personally lost a lot of Eth and tokens to hacking, and I'm a little wiser now. **Use a hardware wallet!** I've read through all the posts on your reddit thread here : https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5y4wg7/do_not_use_myetherwalletcom/ .

**My Speculation:**

I'll presume for argument's sake that you weren't phished. Your computer could be compromised with a RAT, the hacker took a copy of your virtual machine image and has been brute-forcing your VM's password for the past 4 weeks.

The hacker would only need access to your computer once, to copy the VM image, then they don't need your computer anymore. Once they crack your VM's password they've got access to all your keys.

It is very very unlikely anything to do with myetherwallet.com

Comment: Yes i'm 1000% sure,  i logged only once , created account, transferred ETH, and that is it....
next time i logged, ETH was gone already...

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank You for Your time and answers, I know that they are no responsible directly..... my point is that it's relatively easy to stole money through mew. 
And you will never know....
Why leave my CEX money, or Poloniex if they hacked everything....
They have more secure logins, 2fas, notifications and everything....
I had as much money on cex.... and thank God, everything is still there....

Comment: I'we made peace that i lost, for me,  a lot of money, ( here , people work for 200$ monthly...) and i'm going on.... but not on MEW ofc.....Somewhere where i feel secure...where i will get a mail that someone is doing something, that someone is logging or trying something....
I know they don't have mail dont have this and that....
BUT: WHY dont implement something more to make this things impossible...